# How to change safari search engine Mac OS

Tags: macos, finder, safari, safari-extensions, javascript

I want to change safari default search engine by native app or safari extension however it's possible. 
I have tried to **change preference** `(com.apple.safari.plist)` file but there is no key to related safari search engine. 
I also change in `.globlerpreference.plist` but no effect on safari browser is there any file appear in finder thats content safari default search engine.

Comment: What version of macOS are you using?

Comment: currently I using high Sierra but I give support 10.9+

Answer (score 1):

You might find [this Stack Exchange Answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/321805/safari-11-1-search-engine-preference-reverts-to-google) provides a solution:

*There are two places to select the search engine. Setting the search engine from Safari's URL bar overrides whatever's set in Safari > Preferences > Search. My Safari had Google set from the URL bar, and whatever I set in Safari Preferences was immediately reverted to Google.*

*To reset the default search engine in Safari's URL bar, click on the magnifying glass icon, which appears at the left side of the URL bar when no page is displayed. A dropdown appears. Then select which engine you'd choose. Luckily, I was content with DDG, one of the only four choices presented.*

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Safari > Preferences > Search there is a pop-up that lets you select the search engine from a pre-defined list.

Unfortunately I have no idea how to change that pre-defined list (if that is what you need), perhaps it is somewhere inside the .app package(?)

Comment: I already find in .app package but there is nothing related to change search engine but thanks to your opinion